# Weibel 1.2.7: Existence of exact sequences of complexes.

Tags: homological-algebra

> If $C$ is a complex, show that there are exact sequences of complexes:
> $$
> 0 \longrightarrow Z(C) \longrightarrow C \stackrel{d}{\longrightarrow} B(C)[-1] \longrightarrow 0;
> $$
> $$
> 0 \longrightarrow H(C) \longrightarrow C / B(C) \stackrel{d}{\longrightarrow} Z(C)[-1] \longrightarrow H(C)[-1] \longrightarrow 0.
> $$

$$
\cdots\xrightarrow{} C_{n+1}\xrightarrow{d_{n+1}}C_{n}\xrightarrow{d_{n}}C_{n-1}\xrightarrow{d_{n-1}}\cdots
$$

I know there is an injective map $i_n: Z_n(C)\to C_n$, since $Z_n(C)=\ker(d_n)\subset C_n$.
Could you please tell me how to get other maps? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$d$ is a morphism from $C_n$ to $C_{n-1}$. Its kernel is $Z_n(C)$ and its image is $B_{n-1}(C)$. Therefore $d$ induces an exact sequence
$$0\to Z_n(C)\to C_n\to B_{n-1}(C)\to0.$$
Assembling these for all $n$ gives your first exact sequence.

Again consider $d:C_n\to C_{n-1}$. Its kernel is $Z_n(C)$ but that contains $B_n(C)$
so $d$ induces a morphism $C_n/B_n(Z)\to C_{n-1}$ which by abuse of notation we'll
also call $d$. The image of our new $d$ is the same as that of our new $d$
and is $B_{n-1}(C)$, but that is contained in $Z_{n-1}(C)$. Then
$d$ induces a morphism $C_n/B_n(C)\to B_{n-1}(C)$ which composed with the
inclusion $B_{n-1}(C)\to Z_{n-1}(C)$ becomes a morphism
$C_n/B_n(C)\to Z_{n-1}(C)$. Again, abuse notation and call that $d$.
The kernel of $d$ is $H_n(C)$ and its cokernel is $H_{n-1}(C)$. That gives
your second exact sequence.

Comment: Thanks for your help!